# How can I download my app package directly from app store connect?

Tags: ios, applications, xcode, app-store-connect

I had an ios app created, which has been uploaded but not yet released on the App Store.

However, I have not been able to get hold of the original files used to create app from the developer who made it.

Is there a way to download the files directly from my App Store Connect account- I want to be able to run the app locally via XCode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title and body ask two different things, ‘app package’ and ‘original files’.

- The ‘original files’, source code, is never uploaded to Apple. You will need to get these from the original developer.
- The compiled ‘app package’ in an .ipa bundle for execution on an iOS device (not Simulator) cannot be downloaded from App Store Connect.

  > Apple does not provide any way of retrieving an upload app/IPA. It's neither possible through App Store Connect nor the App Store Connect API.

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60947606/download-ipa-build-via-app-store-connect-api
- If you want to run the app on a physical device without releasing to the App Store, add the app to TestFlight and enable internal testing.